# Devstack single interface not working on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-neutron

Trying to bring up openstack using devstack scripts with branch `stable/wallaby`(also tried with `stable/xena)` with single interface with reference configuration from [here](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/wallaby/guides/neutron.html). However while stacking, installation fails due to `arping`. Below is my `netplan`, `local.conf` and `error.log`

**netplan**

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.2.25/24
      gateway4: 192.168.2.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
        search: [kp.local]
#    enp0s8:
#      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

**local.conf**

```
[[local|localrc]]

# DEST=/opt/stack
# DATA_DIR=$DEST/data


LIBVIRT_TYPE=kvm

# ===== BEGIN localrc credentials =====
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=secret
RABBIT_PASSWORD=secret
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_TOKEN=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
DATABASE_TYPE=secret
# ================END ==================

# ===== BEGIN localrc component branches =====
KEYSTONE_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
NOVA_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
NEUTRON_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
CINDER_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
GLANCE_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
REQUIREMENTS_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
HORIZON_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
MAGNUM_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
OCTAVIA_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
HEAT_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
PLACEMENT_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
# ================END ==================

HOST_IP=192.168.2.25
SERVICE_HOST=192.168.2.25
MYSQL_HOST=192.168.2.25
RABBIT_HOST=192.168.2.25
GLANCE_HOSTPORT=192.168.2.25:9292

## Neutron options
Q_USE_SECGROUP=True
FLOATING_RANGE="192.168.2.0/24"
IPV4_ADDRS_SAFE_TO_USE="10.0.0.0/22"
Q_FLOATING_ALLOCATION_POOL=start=192.168.2.250,end=192.168.2.254
PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY="192.168.2.1"
PUBLIC_INTERFACE=enp0s3

# Open vSwitch provider networking configuration
Q_USE_PROVIDERNET_FOR_PUBLIC=True
OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE=br-ex
PUBLIC_BRIDGE=br-ex
OVS_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=public:br-ex

disable_service tempest
disable_service c-api
disable_service c-vol
disable_service c-sch
```

**error.log**

```
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:631  DEFAULT_ROUTE_GW=192.168.2.1
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:632  local ADD_OVS_PORT=
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:633  local DEL_OVS_PORT=
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:634  local ARP_CMD=
++lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:636  ip -f inet a s dev enp0s3 scope global primary
++lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:636  awk '{ print $2, $3, $4; exit }'
++lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:636  grep inet
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:636  IP_BRD='192.168.2.25/24 brd 192.168.2.255'
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:638  '[' 192.168.2.1 '!=' '' ']'
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:639  ADD_DEFAULT_ROUTE='sudo ip -f inet r replace default via 192.168.2.1 dev br-ex'
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:642  [[ True == \T\r\u\e ]]
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:643  ADD_OVS_PORT='sudo ovs-vsctl --may-exist add-port br-ex enp0s3'
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:646  [[ False == \T\r\u\e ]]
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:650  [[ 192.168.2.25/24 brd 192.168.2.255 != '' ]]
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:651  IP_DEL='sudo ip addr del 192.168.2.25/24 brd 192.168.2.255 dev enp0s3'
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:652  IP_REPLACE='sudo ip addr replace 192.168.2.25/24 brd 192.168.2.255 dev br-ex'
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:653  IP_UP='sudo ip link set br-ex up'
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:654  [[ inet == \i\n\e\t ]]
++lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:655  grep -o -E '(.*)/'
++lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:655  awk '{ print $1; exit }'
++lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:655  echo 192.168.2.25/24 brd 192.168.2.255
++lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:655  cut -d / -f1
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:655  IP=192.168.2.25
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:656  ARP_CMD='sudo arping -A -c 3 -w 5 -I br-ex 192.168.2.25 '
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:662  sudo ip addr del 192.168.2.25/24 brd 192.168.2.255 dev enp0s3
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:662  sudo ip addr replace 192.168.2.25/24 brd 192.168.2.255 dev br-ex
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:662  sudo ip link set br-ex up
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:662  sudo ovs-vsctl --may-exist add-port br-ex enp0s3
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:662  sudo ip -f inet r replace default via 192.168.2.1 dev br-ex
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:662  sudo arping -A -c 3 -w 5 -I br-ex 192.168.2.25
ARPING 192.168.2.25 from 192.168.2.25 br-ex
Sent 3 probes (3 broadcast(s))
Received 0 response(s)
+lib/neutron-legacy:_move_neutron_addresses_route:1  exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:507                  local r=1
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:508                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:508                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:517                  '[' -f /tmp/tmp.GwhIdPn4j8 ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:518                  rm /tmp/tmp.GwhIdPn4j8
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:522                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:417               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:524                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:525                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:527                  type -p generate-subunit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:528                  generate-subunit 1635311963 363 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:530                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:533                  /usr/bin/python3.8 /opt/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2021-10-27-052526.txt for details
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:542
```

However if I enable `flat` interface and comment out `Q_USE_PROVIDERNET_FOR_PUBLIC` field as shown in below `local.conf` though `arping` works and ovs configuration gets created, however while dowloading the `cirros` image installation fails. The reason being name resolution fails, able to ping the `8.8.8.8` though curl of `google.co.in` fails with name or service not found.

**local.conf**

```
[[local|localrc]]

# DEST=/opt/stack
# DATA_DIR=$DEST/data


LIBVIRT_TYPE=kvm

# ===== BEGIN localrc credentials =====
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=secret
RABBIT_PASSWORD=secret
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_TOKEN=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
DATABASE_TYPE=secret
# ================END ==================

# ===== BEGIN localrc component branches =====
KEYSTONE_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
NOVA_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
NEUTRON_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
CINDER_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
GLANCE_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
REQUIREMENTS_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
HORIZON_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
MAGNUM_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
OCTAVIA_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
HEAT_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
PLACEMENT_BRANCH=stable/wallaby
# ================END ==================

HOST_IP=192.168.2.25
SERVICE_HOST=192.168.2.25
MYSQL_HOST=192.168.2.25
RABBIT_HOST=192.168.2.25
GLANCE_HOSTPORT=192.168.2.25:9292

## Neutron options
Q_USE_SECGROUP=True
FLOATING_RANGE="192.168.2.0/24"
IPV4_ADDRS_SAFE_TO_USE="10.0.0.0/22"
Q_FLOATING_ALLOCATION_POOL=start=192.168.2.250,end=192.168.2.254
PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY="192.168.2.1"
#PUBLIC_INTERFACE=enp0s3
FLAT_INTERFACE=enp0s3

# Open vSwitch provider networking configuration
#Q_USE_PROVIDERNET_FOR_PUBLIC=True
#OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE=br-ex
#PUBLIC_BRIDGE=br-ex
#OVS_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=public:br-ex


disable_service tempest
disable_service c-api
disable_service c-vol
disable_service c-sch
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue and tracked it donw to be this bug: https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/247. So either manually install a recent version if iputils-arping or e.g create a wrapper script and correct the exit code